# How to remove collection type name from results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

When I run this query

```
create type type_4 as table of varchar2(20) ;

SELECT
    department_id,
    CAST(COLLECT(first_name) AS type_4) names
FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id;
```

I am getting below result

[image]

My question is How do i remove **"HR.TYPE_4"** from the result because its irrelevant  and also

why its (**HR.TYPE_4**)coming in the result set because i am just giving a simple select.

Comment: How collections are displayed will depend on the tool you are using. In PL/SQL Developer for example, the results grid shows "<Collection>" with clickable box, so this isn't a PL/SQL or SQL issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why its (HR.TYPE_4)coming in the result set because I am just giving a simple select.

Because you collected the names into a nested table collection. The user interface you are using is helpfully displaying all the relevant information including the data type of the collection and the values in the collection.

You may not find it helpful but the developers of whatever user interface you are using decided that that was the most informative way of displaying a collection to the user. You can investigate if there are any preferences that you can set on the user interface to change how it displays it or you can look at alternative methods of formatting the data.

---

If you just want a list of names then you do not need a collection and can use `LISTAGG` to get a single formatted string:

```sql
SELECT department_id,
       LISTAGG(first_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY first_name) AS names
FROM   employees 
GROUP BY department_id;
```

Comment: @MTO you are saying that if i put the selected columns into clause  the "HR.TYPE_4" wont come in the variable ?

Comment: @Erik No, that's not it. Whatever tool you are using displays collections this way. Other tools display them differently, e.g. PL/SQL Developer will display '<Collection>' with a button next to it that shows the values in a new window. MTO's suggestion is to use the `listagg` function to create a comma-separated list instead of a collection.